# Using methods passed in to other methods

Tags: java, methods, parameters

So in trying to create some built in error detection, I thought I might want to specify a method to be called when an error occurs. However, I am having trouble getting this to work how I want it to. What am I doing wrong / how do I pass in a method to use it in another method?

```java
/**
     * Gets the input of a user
     *
     * @param prompt input prompt
     * @param type   datatype object you want as an output
     * @param errorMethod Method that executes if there is an invalid input
     * @param params parameters for the errorMethod
     * @return input value
     */
    public static <T> T repeatedGetInput(String prompt, Class<T> type, Method errorMethod, Object... params){
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        while (true) {
            System.out.print(prompt);
            String input = scn.nextLine();
            if (type.equals(String.class))
                return type.cast(input);//String doesn't have a .valueOf(String str) so I made an edge case
            try {
                Method valueOf = type.getMethod("valueOf", String.class);
                return type.cast(valueOf.invoke(null, input));
            } catch (Exception e) {
                try{
                    errorMethod.invoke(null, params);
                    ConsoleFunctions.cls();
                } catch (Exception x) {
                    x.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Invocation:

```java
int value = ConsoleFunctions.repeatedGetInput("Enter a number: ", Integer.class, MessagePrompts.invalidInput() );
```

I end up getting an error saying this.

```
              Required type      Provided
type:         Class<T>           Class<Integer>
errorMethod  :Method             void

reason: void is not compatible with Method
```

The method declaration I am passing in looks like this, and I see that it is return type void.

```java
public static void invalidInput( ) {
```

Comment: You are mixing up some things here. Using `MessagePrompts.invalidInput()` as a parameter first evaluates that method call, the passes the return value of that method as a parameter. So you are not passing a `Method` reference but a value. In this case, the method "returns" `void`, so there is no value and this does not even compile.

Comment: Passing a `Method` uses the java reflection api, which is clunky and too complex for what you want to achieve. Starting with java8, you can make use of function references, so use `MessagePrompts::invalidInput()` and change the parameter type to a functional interface such as `Runnable`.

Comment: How would I be able to use parameters in the functional interface that get passed in to `repeatedGetInput()`?